# twitter bot with api

Tags: api, twitter, bots

im writing a bot that replies to a user message instantly. from what i've read their api only allows checking updates every minute or so.

it's there a push feature or a 3rd party service that pushes the new message to my server right away?

i've seen bots that can do this.

Comment: can you share more details? you want to send a message to your server or to the user? 

is your message a fixed standard reply or does it depend on the message that the user sends?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter allows white listing of apps. Then you are only limited to something like 20 or 200 thousand requests an hour. You might want to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [tweebot](https://github.com/caxap/tweebot) python micro framework.

> A Python library to build twitter bots over tweepy library. It's a very simple 
>   and flexible way to create your own bot.

Answer (score 0):

First [apply](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access) for Developper Twitter Account.
And setup your app using the official list of [librairies](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/v2). (python, js and many others available)

If you are using JS, you might not want to use [Twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) because it is only working with v1.1. You might prefer [Twitter-api-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2) but be careful as for now, media upload is [not available](https://trello.com/b/myf7rKwV/twitter-developer-platform-roadmap) on v2.

I advise you request an Elevated access from your Developer personal space, which is immediate, and will allow you to use v1 functionalities.

Here is a sample for tweeting an image using twitter-api-v2 (using Elevated account with v1)

```
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';
import { twitterconf } from './conf.js';

const client = new TwitterApi({
    appKey: twitterconf.CONSUMER_KEY,
    appSecret: twitterconf.CONSUMER_SECRET,
    accessToken: twitterconf.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    accessSecret: twitterconf.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

    const image = await client.v1.uploadMedia('/path/to/image.png');
    const newTweet = await twitterClient.v1.tweet('Hello World!', 
    { media_ids: image });
```